# Which is the best way to convert/change an existing drupal site to a resposive pattern?

Tags: drupal, responsive-design

Which is the best way to convert/change an existing drupal site to a responsive pattern? I have searched lot, but not getting any right direction or guideline. My current site is running with drupal 7 and zen theme. Do I need to change the theme to responsive one like bootstrap or there have any other better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the answer in your question! I used the Bootstrap theme for Drupal to make my websites responsive. It works perfectly. You can find it here:

[Bootstrap project for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap)

The theme is shipped with sub-theme starter kit you can use to pimp your own theme safely.

Comment: is there any helpful tutorials for how its use properly? Because I am getting very hard to implement this theme.

Comment: Not that I know... First step: did you manage to create and enable the subtheme in your Drupal installation?

Comment: That part I have already completed but not sure how move fwd, like menu for low resolution devices etc. So I am looking for a tutorial/guidline.

Comment: The menu for low resolution is automatic. You can test it in Firefox (press Atl+Cmd+M to get a mobile resolution emulation).

Comment: In windows need to press shift+ctrl+m, with firefox and web developer addon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't convert the Drupal site but the HTML output, to responsive. 
How the HTMl is generated (the Drupal theme) is not relevant.

Regardless of what theme you are using, something that I found useful is just open your website in Chrome, and using Developer tools, I add media queries as required to a new CSS, fixing only what looks too cluttered or small in the simulated device.

Some steps include:

1. Add a new folder to workspace (Sources tab)
2. Add a local (initially empty) css link to the drupal header (to work with the actual site, or you'll have to take the task to generate an off-line version of your site, fixing all the links to point to your local computer, or to setup that theme in a local server, as MAMP)
3. replace all the WIDTHs from container that prevent the site to be reduced with the browser's viewport (as you reduce the window size) with MAX-WIDTHs (same value), and set a new WIDTH to 100%. Now your design will be flexible under the original width.
4. hide, float, or change the position of divs to flow nicer with the new viewport width.
5. A trick I use a lot with big marketing elements (not article content with lots of text) is to make them elastic, so they look always the same relatively to the viewport. To accomplish that: re-define font-sizes AND all dimensions in em. Then and add "font-size: 1vw;" to the first parent that can be proportional to the viewport's width or matches the full viewport, and when your viewport resizes, all the elements will scale as well.

   6. setup a few classes as .mobile-hidden or .desktop-only to hide/show redundant elements in mobile view.
   7. (Obvious) make texts bigger and add give enough padding to small elements to be easily touchable.

Then just upload your CSS to the theme and change the url in the link you created before in the header.

Voilá: responsive theme.

Note: Keep in mind many scripts these days modify the DOM and new elements might need to be styled later, once you run some cart, or functionality which generates/changes elements and their styles.

Good luck.